# `else if` condition not properly working in my program in c

Tags: c, if-statement

I am new and I don't know to to resolve this error.

When I give inputs for the third `else if` statement condition  it gives the output as salary =0.

Can anyone explain why this happening?

I want to get the answer as :the salary of the candidate = 7000
but the output shows as : the salary of the candidate = 0

```
/******************* calculating the salary *********************/
/***** bitwise operator ***********/

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     char gen;
     int qual, y_o_s, sal = 0 ;
     printf ( "Enter Gender, Years of Service and Qualifications ( 0 = G, 1 = PG ):\n" );
     printf("enter the  gen, y_o_s, qual, \n");
     scanf("%c\n%d\n%d", &gen, &y_o_s, &qual);

     if (gen == 'M' && y_o_s >= 10 && qual == 1)
       sal = 15000;
     else if ((gen == 'M' && y_o_s >= 10 && qual == 0) || 
         (gen = 'M' && y_o_s < 10 && qual == 1))
       sal = 10000;
     else if (gen == 'M' && y_o_s < 10 && qual == 0)
       sal = 7000;
     else if (gen == 'F' && y_o_s >= 10 && qual == 1)
       sal= 12000;
     else if (gen == 'F' && y_o_s >= 10 && qual == 0)
       sal = 9000;
     else if (gen == 'F' && y_o_s < 10 && qual == 1)
       sal = 10000;
     else if (gen == 'F' && y_o_s >= 10 && qual == 0)
       sal = 6000;

    printf("the salary of the candidat = %d\n", sal);

     return 0;
}
```

I want to get the answer as :the salary of the candidate = 7000
but the output shows as : the salary of the candidate = 0.

Comment: first two if conditions working fine after that if conditions are not working properly

Comment: duty c290, Post your exact input used.

Comment: Some practical rules of thumb to save you frustration along the way of learning: 1. auto-indent or auto-format your code (get editor/IDE which an do it). 2. always use `{}` even when you don't have to (with `if`, loops etc). 3. always check return value of `scanf` (read the docs to see what it means). 4. have final `else` in that kind of if-else ladder, even if it is just `} else { puts("ERROR else"); }` to see if none of your conditions match.

Comment: Use a debugger and single-step through your program to see what's happening.

Comment: The scanf seems to be assigning a value to the (undeclared) variable `sex`, but you are checking a variable named `gen`.  Presumably, this is a cut-n-paste error.  It is difficult to diagnose code that is not accurately reproduced in the question.

Comment: Since `gen` is uninitialized, the attempt to compare it to `M` leads to undefined behavior.  Further speculation is pointless.  Use `&gen` instead of `&sex` in the scanf and CHECK THE RETURN VALUE.  If `scanf` does not assign a value then `gen` remains uninitialized and the UB is still present.

Comment: Interesting that the salary is dependent on candidate's sex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a value to `gen`

```
else if ((gen == 'M' && y_o_s >= 10 && qual == 0) || 
  (gen = 'M' && y_o_s < 10 && qual == 1))
       ^
```

So when you get to your next line `gen` is no longer what you expect.

```
else if (gen == 'M' && y_o_s < 10 && qual == 0)
             ^^
```

And then improve the code with [SparKot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/835145/sparkot)s suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Alter your `if-else-if` ladder like :

```c
#define POST_GRAD 1
#define SEX_MALE  'M'
     
     if (SEX_MALE == gen) {
        if (POST_GRAD == qual) {
            sal = (y_o_s >= 10) ? 15000 : 10000;
        } else { // undergrad
            sal = (y_o_s >= 10) ? 10000 : 7000;
        }
     } else { // not Male
        if (POST_GRAD == qual) {
            sal = (y_o_s >= 10) ? 12000 : 10000;
        } else { // undergrad
            sal = (y_o_s >= 10) ? 9000 : 6000;
        }
     }
```

It's easier to follow. Notice, that constants like `POST_GRAD` are on the left side comparator `==`, it helps compiler catch unintended typos like `=` for comparisons.

Also, you may want those salaries at one place like :

```c
#define MALE_PG_EXP_SAL 15000
#define MALE_UG_EXP_SAL 10000
// and so on
#define FEMALE_UG_EXP_SAL 9000
#define FEMALE_UG_INEXP_SAL 6000
```

When they change, you can find them at one place to modify.

PS: I wouldn't want to work at this place.